# What does it mean when you declare a variable with two sets of square brackets?

Tags: objective-c

I've just came across something like

```
float a[4][5];
```

I know one pair of square brackets after a variable declares it as a C-array, but what does two pairs do?

Comment: That is standard C notation for a multi-dimension array.  (But there be dragons.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a two dimensional C array with 4 columns and 5 rows of floats.
You can access the individual values by going a[x][y].

Comment: Hmm, does it go to higher dimensions? Like a[3][4][5]?

Comment: Absolutely. The compiler does not care.

Comment: Eric is correct there is no limit on them (well I guess if you ran out of memory trying to allocate an array.) I would recommend not using a C array instead use NSArray or NSMutableArray (There is a lot of optimisation that goes on behind the scenes for these Objects). You can always point objects in your NSArray to another NSArray to create a multidimensional array.

Comment: Hmm, yes I've used array within array and it worked well. Just thought this might be an even better shortcut, guess not haha :)